# Should marionette backbone model fields be automatically available for templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, models, marionette

I have a collection calling a remote REST server and getting back a JSON object containing fields including arrays. My Model is being called on each iteration through the collection, and I can get one of the fields to render in my template. Here's where things get strange...

If I do the following in the template:

```
<%= name %>
```

I can get the name field to output. However, any other fields will not render, unless I create some defaults at the beginning of the Model thus:

```
defaults: {
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    age: ''
}
```

So, if I include this, I can render those fields. Should I have to do that on a model to use it's fields?

... as requested by n8eil

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="pos-list-item">
    <%= name %>, <%= description %>, <%= cost %>
</script>
```

JSON Object:

```
{
    "itemCount": 3,
    "items": [
        {
            "uri": "/item/1234",
            "name": "Soda Drink",
            "description": "A fizzy drink",
            "price": [
            {
                "costType": "A",
                "cost": 3.5
            }
        ],
        "live": true,
        "created": "2013-10-07 18:22:29"
    },
    {
        "uri": "/item/12345",
        "name": "Choco bar",
        "description": "A nice snack",
        "price": [
            {
                "costType": "B"
                "cost": 1.75
            }
        ],
        "live": true,
        "created": "2013-10-07 18:22:29"
    }
    ]
}
```

Changed some data for project privacy but this is essentially the layout of the JSON object. I need 'name', 'description' and 'cost' to appear in the template as above. I can log 'price' out to the console and it shows as an object but I cannot single out the 'cost' field...

Comment: can you include a sample of the template (specifically including the fields which do not render) as well as the JSON object coming back from the server?

Comment: @ne8il - Just edited the code above to reflect the code as asked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/eHoPAri/1/edit?html,js,console,output

I went ahead and mocked up some Marionette structures for this data, not sure if they're close to what you're doing. The only thing I needed to change for the template was that 'cost' is inside an object inside the 'price' array, so you need to reference it by '`price[0].cost`'. Otherwise no, you should not need default properties on a model in order for them to be rendered in the template, but you will get an error if you try to reference a property not found on the model.

You could also put in a method to add a 'cost' property to the model when it's loaded so you don't have to reference it from the array :

```
    var itemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      parse : function(response, options){
         return _.extend(response, { 'cost' : response['price'][0]['cost'] })
      }
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply. This works perfectly. I still can't have the fields displayed unless I set up defaults: {name: "", cost: ""}, not sure why that is, but if I do that, I can now (using your code) get at the nested data in the JSON object. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the field would have to exist when rendering that template. However, you could modify the template and not have to include defaults:

```
<%= name ? name : '' %>
```